# How to prove the helicity operator is a Casimir operator for massless particles?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, lie-algebra, helicity

I am reading the classification of irreducible unitary Poincaré group representations. It seems that for massless particles, the momentum operator and the Pauli-Lubanski operator get aligned so the squared helicity is used as the second Casimir operator to label the representation.

I'm wondering if there is any proof justifying that the squared helicity operator is a Casimir operator? Or equivalently, how to prove that the squared helicity operator commutes with every element in the Lie algebra of the Poincaré group.

Specifically, how to calculate $[M_{\mu\nu}, h^2]$ where $h=\frac{P\cdot S}{P_0}$?

Comment: The usual way to prove this - like for any Casimir - is to just write down the commutator of every generator with $W^2$ and do the (perhaps tedious) computation that it's zero. What problem do you have in doing that? Are you just asking for someone else to do that computation for you?

Comment: @ACuriousMind I think this is a common question so the proof should exist in some textbooks or literature. I read Wigner's original paper but couldn't find it. So I asked this question to find references. But you are right, maybe I can try to work it out by myself.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I made some attempts... but I got stuck at calculating the commutator because the denominator in the helicity is an operator. Do you know how to calculate?

Comment: If that's the problem - why try to do it for some special massless case? $W^2$ is a Casimir operator, not only a constant in specific representations.

Comment: @ACuriousMind It's certainly true that $W^2$ is a Casimir operator. But I suppose that we need two Casimir operators to index a representation? In the massive case, we have $W^2$ and $P^2$. But in the massless case, these two become equivalent, which is the reason why the helicity is introduced

Comment: Just because $W^2$ and $P^2$ have the same value there does not mean you need anything else! They're still two different data points that just accidentally coincide. Note that there are so-called "continuous spin representations" that are also massless but don't have $W\propto P$, so this isn't automatic from the condition of masslessness!

Comment: Section 10.4.4 of Wu-Ki Tung. Have you worked out the resulting Euclidean group for a light-like vector (1,0,0,1)? [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli–Lubanski_pseudovector#Massless_fields).

Comment: @ACuriousMind Thank you, I think what you said makes sense. I thought the two values of helicity constitute a 2-d rep. After seeing Cosmas Zachos 's reference I understand that they constitute two 1-d reps!